# MySQL Error code 1452 occurs but values and tables do exist

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I cannot for the life of me figure out where did I mess up. I Have the following tables, made using this SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    pwd TEXT NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    user_type VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    user_status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Users_Index
ON Users (username);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Clients(
    client_id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    client_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    middle_name VARCHAR(25),
    related_to VARCHAR(10),
    relation_type VARCHAR(25),
    ssn_ein VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
    manager VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    entity_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    client_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    state VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    zip INT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    phone VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    notes TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(manager) REFERENCES Users(username)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX username_index
ON Clients(manager);
```

I tried to insert data into the Clients table but it gave me error 1452, which is for when a constraint check has failed. Thing is, I already have data in the Users table, I TRIPLE checked for typos, I added the indexes to both tables to no avail, I checked that the reference was pointing to the right table, I checked to see that the engines were both InnoDB as well as the collations being exact, and both username and manager columns are the same exact datatype. I have checked the MySQL documentation and followed all requisites to the best of my knowledge. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Here is the sample data:

```
INSERT INTO Clients VALUES (
    client_id = "123456",
    client_name = "John Doe",
    first_name = "John",
    last_name = "Doe",
    middle_name = "Michael",
    related_to = NULL,
    relation_type = NULL,
    ssn_ein = "123-456-7890",
    date_of_birth = "1990-01-01",
    manager = "OzzyTheGiant",
    entity_type = "Individual",
    client_status = "Active",
    address = "123 Main St.",
    city = "Anytown",
    state = "XX",
    zip = 78550,
    email = "john.doe@example.com",
    phone = "123-555-7890",
    notes = "self-employed"
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's cause the row/record you are trying to insert into `Clients` table doesn't exists in `Users` table and thus the error. Since the record doesn't exists in parent table itself, how can you expect to insert in child table? that's not possible.

Also, your `INSERT` query syntax wrong. Your schema creation script should look like below. See a demo fiddle here: <kbd>[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04769)</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    pwd TEXT NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    user_type VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    user_status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Users_Index
ON Users (username);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Clients(
    client_id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    client_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    middle_name VARCHAR(25),
    related_to VARCHAR(10),
    relation_type VARCHAR(25),
    ssn_ein VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
    manager VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    entity_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    client_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    state VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    zip INT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    phone VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    notes TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(manager) REFERENCES Users(username)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX username_index
ON Clients(manager);

INSERT INTO `Users` VALUES('OzzyTheGiant', 'scxcxx','test1','test2','test','test','test');

INSERT INTO Clients VALUES (
'123456',
'John Doe',
'John',
'Doe',
'Michael',
NULL,
NULL,
'123-456-78',
'1990-01-01',
'OzzyTheGiant',
'Individual',
'Active',
'123 Main St.',
'Anytown',
'XX',
78550,
'john.doe@example.com',
'123-555-7890',
'self-employed'
);
```

Comment: (FACEPALM)...... you wanna know why I wrote the the INSERT statement like that? Because i'm using Peewee in a Python flask app and I keep forgetting to switch syntax between python and sql. How dumb of me. You win! .... btw. The data in the Users table did exist so that was not it.

Comment: Also, for anyone having this problem in the future, one thing that can be learned from my simple mistake is that MySQL doesn't tell you if it's a syntax error, for some reason it spews out error 1452, as if it interpretes everything between the commas as the value for each column